# Convert Number to IP Address (v4)

Tags: vb.net, network-programming, ip-address

I'm trying to convert a four digit number into an IP Address. For example:

0001 ---> *.192.1.01

0011 ---> *.192.11.01

0111 ---> *.192.111.01

1111 ---> *.196.87.01

3458 ---> *.205.130.01

I believe the subnet mask is 255.255.192.0.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on the best way to do this in vb.net.

**Other info:**

This is for a simple pinger program where the user inputs a four digit number (the ID of the physical site that they wish to ping.) The IP Addressing scheme is simple, the 2nd & 3rd octet are used as the site number, and the fourth octet is used as the device at the site. I didn't design this scheme, hence why I'm unsure on how to get vb.net to understand it.

**What I've Tried:**

I thought about doing it the following way, which is extremely crude. However this would only work up to *.192.255.01 as I don't know how to split the number between the two octets once it goes over 255 in octet 3.

```
Private Sub btnStartPing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartPing.Click

    Dim Octet1 As Integer = *
    Dim Octet2 As Integer = 192
    Dim Octet3 As Integer = txtSiteID.text
    Dim Octet4 As Integer = 01
    Dim CompleteIP As String = ""

    CompletIP = Octet1 & "." & Octet2  & "." & Octet3 & "." & Octet4 

    'PING CompleteIP

end sub
```

**Solution:**

```
        Dim var1 As Integer = Fix(192 + (NumericUpDown1.Value / 256))
        Dim var2 As Integer = Fix((NumericUpDown1.Value Mod 256))

        MsgBox("Your IP address is: " & "10." & var1 & "." & var2 & "." & "200")
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to split the number in two. Get the first half of the bits and add them to 192 and the second half of the bits are directly used.

```
    Dim number As Integer

    number = 1
    Console.WriteLine("*.{0}.{1}.01", 192 + ((number And &HFF00) >> 8), number And &HFF) ' *.192.1.01

    number = 11
    Console.WriteLine("*.{0}.{1}.01", 192 + ((number And &HFF00) >> 8), number And &HFF) ' *.192.11.01

    number = 111
    Console.WriteLine("*.{0}.{1}.01", 192 + ((number And &HFF00) >> 8), number And &HFF) ' *.192.111.01

    number = 1111
    Console.WriteLine("*.{0}.{1}.01", 192 + ((number And &HFF00) >> 8), number And &HFF) ' *.196.87.01

    number = 3458
    Console.WriteLine("*.{0}.{1}.01", 192 + ((number And &HFF00) >> 8), number And &HFF) ' *.205.130.01
```

Take the number and split it in two

> 3458 = 0x0D82
>
> 0x0D
>     0x82

Then add 192 to the first part

> 0x0D + 192 = 205
>     0x82 = 130

Comment: Thank you, i used a much simpler version but the principle is the same, see my update for details.

Comment: @user3224987 I find mine simpler but I'm glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This should make it

```
Public Function StartPing(txtSiteId As String) As String
    Dim SiteId As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtSiteId)

    'backslash performs integer division (no fractionary part)
    'will throw an error when SiteId results in values greater than 255
    'type Byte allows only values from 0 to 255
    Dim Octet2 As Byte = 192 + (SiteId \ 256)

    'Mod gets rest of division
    Dim Octet3 As Byte = SiteId Mod 256

    Return String.Format("*.{0}.{1}.01", Octet2, Octet3)
End Function
```